# How to create iso/image/installation from Windows XP-installation for use VMware

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vmware, iso-image

I'm using VMware and want to create a virtual machine with Windows XP.

For this I want to use the Windows XP-installation of another computer, I don't have the cd, so I want to create a iso/image (or whatever) using this Windows-installation.

How can I do this?

Comment: You would use `ImageX` from within WinPE

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to create an image from your current system you will need to boot your machine from another partition that isn't the one that you want to save. You may be using [`Clonezilla`](http://clonezilla.org/) for this.

- [Tutorials section of Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/related-articles/)
- [Disk to disk clone](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone)

Comment: Clonezilla won't create a hard drive image for use with vm ware

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a VMware specific clone of existing machine first. According to *VMware Workstation* and it's documentation, you can use function *Virtualize a Physical Machine* from main menu. This function requires **VMware vCenter Converter** installed. You can get it for free on [this link](http://www.vmware.com/go/getconverter).